# RSA key sizes v/s public key sizes

Tags: cryptography, java, rsa, .net

I am new to cryptography. I have an api provided by a bank. The banks says that they are using RSA algorithm with 2048 bits. We used this api first to get the public key. Here is the sample public key(some chars updated for security),

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgqvmScnvYGpQ+exGe9OM2tYM+JGjEZbQ
VxQsnBQ7tfSTc6gSsUSFZdASD7Jrr2Mo1EvcBW+wyuENvS5G+d65EGv2lKlFb7iCgVF2RGw5dDdS
kD7hF1lCnXA6TNi7hMwQWeCInEMTeD1ZR52KvRK4jmLr3EWyujTP/h0oyOpBRc5dvoCOgyi7eSXG
q7uUWUOOZNnTtW/fIixdNQJ28Kz5Mf4HykHZxIPTtjg6I1jZgBdVL6pYgwA2oyHGEOe2ObB6ZeTB
9+meHuTxyIRUtTPSNSK0bfHYT56TwruwgJwnrHjvvM07Lzah69wLvhWAiR2mPQb6juG2zCaU5Mad
sesEuQIDAQAB
```

This look like Base 64 string. The length is 397. I am assuming that this is Modulus and Exponent is AQAB. When I convert this Base64 into bytes it become 294 and (294 * 8)2352 bits. Why 2352 and not 2048 bits?

Actually, I am encrypting an string and sending to Bank api both in Java and in C#. In Java I am doing,

```
public class RSAUtility {
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String key){
    try{
        PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT)));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8")),Base64.DEFAULT);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works very well in java. But in C# I am doing this and it does not work. Any expert can please help me.

```
var keyXml = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>" + key + "</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

EncrptedValue = CryptUtils.Encrypt(keyXml, "MyString", RsaKeyLengths.Bit2048);

    public static string Encrypt(string publicKey, string data, RsaKeyLengths length = RsaKeyLengths.Bit2048)
    {
        // full array of bytes to encrypt
        byte[] bytesToEncrypt;

        // worker byte array
        byte[] block;

        // encrypted bytes
        byte[] encryptedBytes;

        // length of bytesToEncrypt
        var dataLength = 0;

        // number of bytes in key                
        var keySize = 0;

        // maximum block length to encrypt          
        var maxLength = 0;

        // how many blocks must we encrypt to encrypt entire message?
        var iterations = 0;

        // the encrypted data
        var encryptedData = new StringBuilder();

        // instantiate the crypto provider with the correct key length
        var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider((int)length);

        // initialize the RSA object from the given public key
        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(publicKey);

        // convert data to byte array
        bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);

        // get length of byte array
        dataLength = bytesToEncrypt.Length;

        // convert length of key from bits to bytes
        keySize = (int)length / 8;

        // .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider uses SHA1 Hash function
        // use this to work out the maximum length to encrypt per block
        maxLength = ((keySize - 2) - (2 * SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(bytesToEncrypt).Length));

        // how many blocks do we need to encrypt?
        iterations = dataLength / maxLength;

        // encrypt block by block
        for (int index = 0; index <= iterations; index++)
        {
            // is there more than one full block of data left to encrypt?
            if ((dataLength - maxLength * index) > maxLength)
            {
                block = new byte[maxLength];
            }
            else
            {
                block = new byte[dataLength - maxLength * index];
            }

            // copy the required number of bytes from the array of bytes to encrypt to our worker array
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesToEncrypt, maxLength * index, block, 0, block.Length);

            // encrypt the current worker array block of bytes
            encryptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(block, true);

            // RSACryptoServiceProvider reverses the order of encrypted bytesToEncrypt after encryption and before decryption.
            // Undo this reversal for compatibility with other implementations
            Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);

            // convert to base 64 string
            encryptedData.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
        }

        return encryptedData.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly partial answer.

First an aside: you don't need to "secure" a public key by changing bits; the whole purpose and point of public-key cryptography is that it is secure even though the public key is public, which includes available to adversaries.

That publickey form you have is NOT just "modulus and exponent". It is true that the last 3 bytes in this case are the exponent, and by luck the total key encoding happens to be a multiple of 3 so those 3 bytes are the last 4 chars of base64. If you are treating the other 294-3 bytes as the modulus that is very wrong.

What you *do* have, as you correctly stated in the JCA calls, is what Java calls an [X509EncodedKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html) and in standard terms is the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure defined in the (very widely used) X.509 standard. That structure is an ASN.1 SEQUENCE containing an AlgorithmIdentifier which identifies the algorithm using another SEQUENCE this time of an OBJECT IDENTIFIER aka OID or OBJECT which in this case is an OID for RSA and (usually) a parameters field of varying type which in this case is NULL, all of that followed by a BIT STRING containing the algorithm-specific encoding of the publickey value, which for RSA is defined by PKCS#1 as used in [rfc3279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.3.1) or its update [rfc4055](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4055#section-1.2), and is a(nother) SEQUENCE of two INTEGERs which are the modulus and (public) exponent respectively. Every piece of an ASN.1 structure has its own (smallish) "type and length" header.

To be concrete, the value of your "secured" (and presumably wrong) publickey can easily be seen with the `openssl` command line utility `asn1parse` on your data.
The (outer) SPKI sequence of AlgId plus bitstring:

```
c:\work>openssl asn1parse <temp.b64
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   19:d=1  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING
```

The (inner) RSAPublicKey within the bitstring (with the number values in hex):

```
c:\work>openssl asn1parse <temp.b64 -strparse 19
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: INTEGER           :82ABE649C9EF606A50F9EC467BD38CDA
D60CF891A31196D057142C9C143BB5F49373A812B1448565D0120FB26BAF6328D44BDC056FB0CAE1
0DBD2E46F9DEB9106BF694A9456FB882815176446C39743752903EE11759429D703A4CD8BB84CC10
59E0889C4313783D59479D8ABD12B88E62EBDC45B2BA34CFFE1D28C8EA4145CE5DBE808E8328BB79
25C6ABBB9459438E64D9D3B56FDF222C5D350276F0ACF931FE07CA41D9C483D3B6383A2358D98017
552FAA58830036A321C610E7B639B07A65E4C1F7E99E1EE4F1C88454B533D23522B46DF1D84F9E93
C2BBB0809C27AC78EFBCCD3B2F36A1EBDC0BBE1580891DA63D06FA8EE1B6CC2694E4C69DB1EB04B9
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
```

I presume if you take the part of your actual publickey that is the modulus and represent it in base64 in the `<Modulus>` element that will work, but I don't do dot-NET myself.

Comment: You are right I needed to parse PEM to find Modulus and Exponent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455404/net-equivalent-of-java-keyfactory-getinstance-rsa-rsa-ecb-pkcs1padding